# trigger download after api responce

Tags: php, wordpress-rest-api

I'm using ilovepdf rest api with php, im uploading a pdf file then compress and saving it in my server.
But what i want is  the compressed file to be downloaded automaticly to the user default path browser after the last task is finished.
The compressed file name not as the uploaded file name and idk why.
This code below download damage file that can't be open , and in the console gives this error: Uncaught (in promise) Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received.
How to slove this? i want the file to be downloaded to the user with the same name of the uploaded file , and not to be saved in my server or at least be deleted after the user download it .

```
<?php
// include the autoloader
require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');
// if manual installation has been used, comment the line that requires the autoload and uncomment this line:
// require_once('../init.php');

use Ilovepdf\CompressTask;

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
    // Check if the file was uploaded without errors
    if (isset($_FILES["pdf_file"]) && $_FILES["pdf_file"]["error"] === 0) {
        // Get the temporary file name and original name of the uploaded file
        $tempFileName = $_FILES["pdf_file"]["tmp_name"];
        $originalFileName = $_FILES["pdf_file"]["name"];

        // Move the uploaded file to a desired location (optional, you can keep it in the same location)
        $destination = __DIR__ . '/' . $originalFileName;
        if (move_uploaded_file($tempFileName, $destination)) {
            // You can get your key pair from https://developer.ilovepdf.com/user/projects
            $myTask = new CompressTask('public_key', 'secret_key');

            // Add the file from user input to the task
            $file = $myTask->addFile($destination, $originalFileName);

            // Process the files
            
            $myTask->execute();

            // Download the compressed file
            
            $myTask->download();
            
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $originalFileName . "\"");
            header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
            header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
            header("Connection: close");

         //handling errors
        } else {
            echo "Error moving the uploaded file.";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Error uploading the file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: "This code below download damage file that can't be open" - whenever you run into that issue, try opening the file with a text-only editor such a Notepad on Windows. Look to see if you see any HTML before or after the "binary" content. This is a common issue when an error or warning or similar is being sent to the output stream along with the file's contents

Comment: Looking at the source, [`$myTask->download()`](https://github.com/ilovepdf/ilovepdf-php/blob/b79c79a9ed3fd65ac611f3cb53917be68af10c34/src/Task.php#L395) has an optional parameter that you can set for the file's name. However, there's also a [`toBrowser()`](https://github.com/ilovepdf/ilovepdf-php/blob/b79c79a9ed3fd65ac611f3cb53917be68af10c34/src/Task.php#L436) which does a lot of work for you automatically as long as you set [`outputFileName`](https://github.com/ilovepdf/ilovepdf-php/blob/b79c79a9ed3fd65ac611f3cb53917be68af10c34/src/Task.php#L111)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried this code in any way, however it appears that you can just set the [`$outputFileName`](https://github.com/ilovepdf/ilovepdf-php/blob/b79c79a9ed3fd65ac611f3cb53917be68af10c34/src/Task.php#L111) on the task and then call the [`toBrowser()`](https://github.com/ilovepdf/ilovepdf-php/blob/b79c79a9ed3fd65ac611f3cb53917be68af10c34/src/Task.php#L436C21-L436C30) method, and you won't have to mess around with any of the headers. Adding a try/catch in there would probably be a good idea.

```php
$myTask = new CompressTask('public_key', 'secret_key');
$myTask->addFile($destination, $originalFileName);
$myTask->execute();
$myTask->outputFileName = $originalFileName;
$myTask->toBrowser();
exit;
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris Haas , the download is working as it should , one little problem with the file naming , the orignal file name changed to long name with numbers and hashtags , can we solve this so orignal file name keeps its name after compression or maybe change it to totaly new name?

Comment: The contents of `$_FILES["pdf_file"]`, specifically `["name"]` are about all you have to work with. I'm not seeing anything in that library's code that alters `outputFileName` in any way.

Comment: thanks man for your quick reply , i integreted the code to use it in my wordpress website , the compress working without any error but something wrong with the download , im using downloadmanager in my pc and it gives this error: dublicate link request , and i can't download the file , i tried in my phone and didn't get the compressed file downloaded

Comment: Hmm... not sure. If this is working, it might help to create a new question specific to the other problem and reference what you have in the comments. I'm not really too familiar with download managers anymore these days. Also, just to check, right after `$myTask->toBrowser();` should be `exit`, no other code, since we can't send HTML and we don't want any errors leaking through.

Comment: I see , ill post another question with modified code , thanks for you support Chris Haas!